# How to extract text before special character from string in Excel?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, excel-2010, trim

I have below text on column A1:

> 100-This_Is_My-Test_200

Looking to get output as below in column B1:

> **100-This_Is_My-Test**

so basically it needs to remove text starting from last _ (underscore)

I tried below:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

Output: **200**

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

Output: **100-This**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))))-1)
```

[image]

Comment: `=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(8),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",CHAR(8),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))))-1)` just a few seconds slower :D

Comment: @Rosetta I use `"}}}"` because of the closeness of both characters on the keyboard, a little quicker than typing `CHAR(8)`.  we can use anything that will not be found in the strings.